# Operar en el formato de FROM_UNIXTIME() en MySql

Tags: mysql

Me preguntaba si habia alguna forma de operar cuando indicas el formato de la funcion FROM_UNIXTIME() de MySql.

El caso concreto con el que estoy es el siguiente..

Tengo una serie de datos agrupados por franjas horarias de 3 horas, muestro un ejemplo:

[image: Tabla de datos]

Para mostrar ese dato uso lo siguiente:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(((TIMESTAMP / 1000) DIV (180 * 60)) * (180 * 60), '%H:%i +3h') AS 'Time range'
```

Lo que me gustaría mostrar seria algo como "00:00 - 02:59" operando de alguna forma en la especificación del formato.

Me da que no se puede, a alguien se le ocurre otra forma?

**Gracias!**

Comment: ¿Qué valores tienes en `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: Tengo timestamp en milisegundos, por eso el dividirlo entre 1000...

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias @Alfabravo

Al final ha quedado de la siguiente manera..

```
CONCAT_WS(' - ',
           FROM_UNIXTIME(((TIMESTAMP / 1000) DIV (180 * 60)) * (180 * 60), '%H:%i'),
           DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(((TIMESTAMP / 1000) DIV (180 * 60)) * (180 * 60)), INTERVAL 3 HOUR), '%H:%i')
       ) AS 'Time range'
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar [`date_add`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) para usar el `from_unixtime` sobre el valor +3h. Luego, concatenar todo con `concat`.

Algo **parecido a**

```
CONCAT(
    FROM_UNIXTIME(((TIMESTAMP / 1000) DIV (180 * 60)) * (180 * 60), '%H:%i'),
    "-",     
    FROM_UNIXTIME(((DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 3 HOUR) / 1000) DIV (180 * 60)) * (180 * 60), '%H:%i')
) AS 'Time range'
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Un saludo!